# How SVD is used for dimensionality reduction?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, svd

Given a $M \times N$ data matrix $ D = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_M)^{T}$.

Applying singular value decomposition to $D$ yields 
$$D = USV^{T} = (u_1, u_2, \cdots, u_M)
\begin{pmatrix}
    s_1 &&0\\
    &\ddots\\
    0& & s_N \\
    \hline
    &0
    \end{pmatrix}_{M\times N}
(v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_N)^{T}
$$

Choose $d$ singular values, we have

$$D' = (u_1, u_2, \cdots, u_M)
\begin{pmatrix}
s_1 & &\\
& \ddots &\\
& & s_d\\
\hline
& 0
\end{pmatrix}_{M \times d} = (f_1, f_2, \cdots, f_M)^{T}$$
in which $D'$ is an $M \times d$ matrix.

**My question is:**

What is the relation between $D'$ and $D$? To be specific, can $f_i$ be interpreted as a reduced version of $x_i$? If so, then where is the effect of the orthogonal matrix $V$?

For me, SVD can be used for tuning the "resolution" of a matrix in another way.

Given $D = USV^{T} = \sum_iu_is_iv_i^{T}$, thus the more singular values we take into account, the better the matrix will be reconstructed.

Comment: Are you looking for the Eckhart-Young theorem?

Comment: @Sycorax I don't know the theorem, so I'm not sure. I just read a paper, in the paper, the original data matrix $D$ is transformed into $D'$ by using SVD as I explained. Then for the resulting $D'$, PCA is applied. So, I think SVD is used as a dimensionality reduction technique.